# How to correctly ack AMQP messages after the HTTP request completed

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

I have a controller method consuming messages from a AMQP queue - but I do not want to acknowledge those messages until I am sure as possible that the client that did the http request got the data (so that no data gets lost in case the http request would fail after leaving the controller method).

So far what I have been able to find is that you can use Spring interceptors to implement the  "afterCompletion" which would be called after the request has been successfully completed. But this feels like overkill?

Answer (score 0):

You can acknowledge after your `http` request has been completed by putting the code to acknowledge below that http call... *like* if exception occurs than don't acknowledge
else acknowledge

```
channel.basicAck(DeliveryTag, false);
```

Comment: Ok, this is what I was thinking - but then I have to do this myself by keeping track of all messages received etc and Spring AMQP does not do this for me, right?

Comment: no you can register a asynchronus listner like SimpleMessageListenerContainer passing the messageListner to it.whenever a message is there it will call on message of messagelistner and you will have to write login there only find it here http://static.springsource.org/spring-amqp/reference/html/sample-apps.html#hello-world-async